# What kind of LEDs are used in this lamp?

Tags: led, lamp

I have many of these lamps in my home.

[image]

They are sold as being LED lamps, but I do not know the proper name of this particular type.

Once I had one with the glass bulb broken and removed I got curious and measured the resistance of a stripe: to my surprise all four were open circuit.

My curiosity is to know the technical constitution of the stripes and if they can be used as LEDs outside of the protective bulb.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_filament

Comment: thanks, now it is clear... was not able to find it without your hint

Comment: [Youtube video from BigClive](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFtfMtFSD8A) showing these things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filaments are small PCBs composed of a few LEDs in series coated with phosphor. This is why they measure as open circuits.

They're normal LEDs so you can use them without the glass, although they likely have a very high forward voltage so be careful.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that's enogh clear now